# React Native download file from Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm developing an application with React Native that connects to Sharepoint Online. I'm able to log into SPO and use "fetch" to get lists' content through the HTTP-Only/Secure cookies rtFa and FedAuth that are automatically set from login response.

Now, I would like to download files from SPO. I found these plugins: [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) and [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs). However, when I try to download a file, I get "*Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.*".

I guess the problem is that the cookies (rtFa & FedAuth) are not passed to the fetch function of these plugins and I can't set them as they are HTTP-Only/Secure. Any ideas how to resolve this issue without writing native code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by contacting the developer of [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob). The problem was due to no cookies mechanism, he kindly added one.

For more information: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/156